# Android webview keyboard covering up input

Tags: android, css, cordova, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

The desired effect for my android application is to have a webview with an input box and content.  When the user clicks on the keyboard, the keyboard pushes the input box up, but does not resize the main content and just overlays ontop of it as seen in the diagram below.

[image]

The problem I'm experiencing is that the keyboard covers the input box and does not push it up.

This is currently a cordova android application.  In the manifest, I have configued

```
 <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name="GigJam" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

Also in the config.xml:

```
   <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
```

I used android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" to prevent the screen from resizing which is what i want since I don't want the content to be squished.  I've also tried configuring the css for the input box to be fixed and absolute (basically tied to the bottom of the webview.

From my understanding, when the keyboard pops up from an edit in the input box, that it would push up the box as well because the input box is constrained to the webview which will be pushed up as well.

Any advice appreciated,
Thanks,
D

Comment: Did you solve this ? I am facing the same issue, normally, in Android, `adjustPan` pushes inputs to the top of the keyboard, so that they are always visible, and as you said, doesn't squish the content. But in my Phonegap app, the input is not pushed up.

Comment: Oh crap i didn't notice that the accepted answer was added by you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has a keyboard event that I listen to.  When the show/hide is trigger, I grab the active input component and transform the box in the y axis by the size of the keyboard height which can be grab from the event in the listener.  I transform back when the show is triggered.

Note: resize needs to be disabled for the android:windowSoftInputMode and set to "adjustPan"

Comment: Which event is that ? I could do a `focus` event, but i assume that this would mess the whole thing up on IOS where the behavior is correct by default.

Comment: Please give exact solution

Answer (score 1):

Use this line:

```
getActivity()
    .getWindow()
    .setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to the activity with the webview in the AndroidManifest.xml

For example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```